# the best practice for performance bettween using parameter in url ?p=2 and Managed bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, viewparams, managed-property

I am using JSF 2.0 and `Icefaces` and `Glassfish` for my project and I want to optimise this application the best I can, and I want to know what is the most optimized method to send parameter.

first 1:
using `/BackOffice/test.xhtml?id=7 in url` 
and     `String a=(String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("id");` in the bean with `@RequestScoped`
and

```
<f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="id"  value="#{id}">
        </f:viewParam>
    </f:metadata>
```

in the jsf

or 
the second :
using backing bean with `@SessionScoped`

Comment: The `requestMap()` approach won't work for request parameters and is clumsy. You need `requestParameterMap()` or better just put a `@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.id}")` on the `private Long id;` declaration line. The viewparam is not strictly necessary in this particular context, unless you'd like to be able to include it in subsequent navigations from the current view.

Comment: "Best practice for performance" is nonsense here. Just use right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to optimize you should start with profiling, I highly doubt the difference between these two will be of any significance.

Request parameters should be passed as request parameters as you will otherwise break bookmarks, browser history, search engine indexing and caching.

Answer (score 1):

Optimized how exactly? SessionScoped beans are going to hold persistent memory which may be bad if you have a high number of users. RequestScope is going to require the id to be passed per request which isn't over expensive either way but does require a request scoped bean to be created per-request.

I generally favor Request params over session params unless the value *really* needs to persist for the duration of the user's time on the site.

Comment: i want to optimise time between request from page to other

Comment: Then favor request params until you *really* need to use the session

Comment: thank you and please if there is another method i can optimise in time and performance or both :),please notice me .

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "optimize the best I can". Optimizing is about making trade-offs. You trade cpu for memory, memory for bandwith, bandwith for cpu and so on.

The method of passing Id is probably the least important of your problems. Just forget it. If you want to optimize, first ask yourself whether you are keeping your view state on client or on server. This is going to make a huge difference (and no, there is no "optimal" choice here, it is a trade-off). The next thing will be - how to handle the database. Do you load your data per-request or do you keep them with your view or session? If you use JPA, do you enable the second-level cache? These are the questions you should be asking. Not a detail about request params.